# Multi-Processing to share memory between processes

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to update a variable of a class by calling a function of the class from a different function which is being run on multi-process.

To achieve the desired result, process (**`p1`**) needs to update the variable "transaction" and which should get then modified by process (**`p2`**)

I tried the below code and I know i should use Multiprocess.value or manager to achieve the desired result and I am not sure of how to do it as my variable to be updated is in another class

Below is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from helper import Helper
camsource = ['a','b'] 
Pros = []




def sub(i):
    HC.trail_func(i)


def main():

  for i in camsource:
     print ("Camera Thread {} Started!".format(i))
     p = Process(target=sub, args=(i))
     Pros.append(p)
     p.start()

  # block until all the threads finish (i.e. block until all function_x calls finish)    
  for t in Pros:
     t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HC = Helper()
    main()
```

Here is the helper code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

class Helper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.transactions = []

    def trail_func(self,preview):

        if preview == 'a':
            self.transactions.append({"Apple":1})
        else:
            if self.transactions[0]['Apple'] == 1:
                self.transactions[0]['Apple'] = self.transactions[0]['Apple'] + 1
            print (self.transactions)
```

Desired Output:
**`p1`**:

```
transactions = {"Apple":1}
```

**`p2`**:

```
transactions = {"Apple":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released [this module](https://github.com/gabriel-milan/Akuanduba) that can help you with your code, as all *data frames* (data models that can hold any type of data), have locks on them, in order to solve concurrency issues. Anyway, take a look at the README file and the examples.

I've made an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57402381/does-pydispatcher-run-the-handler-function-in-a-background-thread) too, if you'd like to check.